# UIPageViewController -presentationCount not firing

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Problem: `UIPageViewController` navigation between pages works fine but:
**1) Navigation dots view not showing up**

**2) Some dataSource methods not called (probably cause for 1.)**

I have following UI setup (basically `UIPageViewController` in `UITableViewCell`)

> UITableViewCell <- UIViewController <- ContainerView <- UIPageViewController

Problem:

**CALLED OK:**

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

**NOT CALLED:**

```
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
```

All setup done after **viewDidLoad**:

```
dataSource = self
setViewControllers([viewController], direction: .reverse, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Note: I'm using another `UIPageViewController` somewhere else in the app directly on the content view -> there all delegate methods are working fine. Another (probably directly related) problem is that navigation dot view is not visible. (Again works fine in case where not embedded).

Anybody experience anything like this?
Why would some dataSource delegate methods be called while others would not called?

I've been looking at this code and all I could find in google for hours but can't move forward.

[UIPageViewController Implementation](http://az-serwer1780942.online.pro/UIPageViewControllerDelegateMethodsNotCalled.txt)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A page indicator will be visible if both methods are implemented, transition style is 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll', and navigation orientation is 'UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal'.**

**Both methods are called in response to a 'setViewControllers:...' call, but the presentation index is updated automatically in the case of gesture-driven navigation.**

**According to Apple Documentation you need to implement both methods and make sure that the controller's transition style is "scroll". Then the Page Indicator will be visible and the functions are called. Please check this.**

**for the visibility of the pageindicator. Add below code in viewdidload**

```
var pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return orderedViewControllers.count
}
    
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    if let currentVC = self.viewControllers!.first {
        let currentIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: currentVC)
        return currentIndex!
    }else{
        return 0
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to say.. Also you're not referencing the 'presentationCount' delegate methods which is the problem i have... Also it looks like you just pasted some random code :)

Comment: i think you have problem in showing the pageindicator. @PawelKlapuch

Comment: + for absolutely brilliant way of configuring UIPageController's page control colors. :thumbsup: :thankyou:

Comment: orderedViewControllers isn't defined.

Comment: Replace with your UIViewcontroller’s array @Oscar

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is self.viewControllers!.first guaranteed to be the current view controller?

Comment: This is not current viewcontroller. this is only first. You can put your logic depends on your requirement. In this question we just check whether delegate method called or not @Oscar

Comment: Seems like a very specific and misleading example, then.

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple Documentation you need to implement both methods *and* make sure that the controller's transition style is "scroll". Then the Page Indicator will be visible and the functions are called. Please check this.

Actually Vishal stated this, but not very clear :)